# How to weight each position of every group of data while deploying this data with VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a doubt that I am not seeing any response or maybe I don't know how to google it. As StackOverFlow is my favourite site to answer my doubts I will post my question.

I deploy data from different portfolios with a VBA process. I already developed the macro in order to put all data necessary. I just need to weight each portfolio to sum 100%. With the example I will explain it better:

[image: The example: two portfolios deployed by VBA]

As you can see, I need to weight each portfolio in order to sum 100%, with an excel formula I would be as easy as divide each market value to the sum of the market value of the portfolio but I want to deploy inside my code.

The number of portfolios is different everytime, also the lines, and all.

How do I integer it?

EDIT:

*ADDING CODE*

```
Sheets("TICKERS").Select

Set TickersRegion = Range("A1").CurrentRegion

Sheets("BLOOMBERG DATA").Select

For BloombergDatamos = 2 To FilasTickers


    Cells(BloombergDatamos, 3) = Application.VLookup(Cells(BloombergDatamos, 2), TickersRegion, 2, 0)
    Cells(BloombergDatamos, 4) = Application.VLookup(Cells(BloombergDatamos, 2), TickersRegion, 4, 0)
    Cells(BloombergDatamos, 9) = Application.VLookup(Cells(BloombergDatamos, 2), TickersRegion, 3, 0)
    Cells(BloombergDatamos, 10) = Application.VLookup(Cells(BloombergDatamos, 2), TickersRegion, 7, 0)
    
    'Calculate the Market Value
    
    Cells(BloombergDatamos, 6).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=+BDP(RC[-4],""PX_LAST"")*RC[-1]"
    
Next BloombergDatamos


End Sub
```

How would I do that "easy" weightings?

Thank you.

Comment: Without any code, or any details about the worksheet, there is nothing to do except give general advice like try inserting a formula `=Value/Sum(Values)` and if you want it rounded, use one of `Floor`, `Ceiling` or `Round`. If you want more specific answers, add more details about your project into the post.

Comment: @Toddleson I will update the code but I don't think it's necessary, the thing is about jumping between groups of data on the formula. The excel formula is easy, but the VBA insertion of the idea, not.

Comment: You can insert formulas into the worksheet. See [Range.Formula](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.formula). You can do things like `Range("A1:A20").Formula = "=B1/SUM($B$1:$B$20)"` which will automatically adjust the formula when applying it to each cell in that 20 cell range. So you only need one line to accomplish this.

Comment: @Toddleson as I tried to describe every deployment of data is with different portfolios, different amount of assets, etc. So how do I separate that? For example, in this case we have 2 portfolios, the column of weightings will have to sum 200% (because each portfolio have to have the own weightings)

Comment: You can use `SUMIF` instead of `SUM` so that the formula only includes values associated with the same portfolio. `Range("E1:E20").Formula = "=G1/SUMIF($A$1:$A$20,A1,$G$1:$G$20)"` And i'm using `20` as a placeholder. In your actual code you can determine the last row # dynamically like `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: Let me clarify @Toddleson on every change of portfolio it changes... I don't know how to explain, let me check:
https://i.imgur.com/VAQNOxU.png